pandas read_sql resulting in Value error: "year -10100 is out of range" caused by corrupted dates in database
I am running a script to migrate data from oracle to postgres. When running the below
df = pd.read_sql(
    query,
    oracle_conn,
)

It is resulting in an error of

ValueError: year -10100 is out of range

For some rows accross thousands there are some dates that are corrupted and have large numbers for the year. For example the below is a corrupted date while the next is a valid one.
10101-11-29 22:58:59000.
2024-03-19 18:25:49.000

Is there any way to alter the read_sql so it still reads in corrupted dates no matter what the year range is?

please show us the query you use to retrieve the data, i would "correct" the data, with the select statement

The query is simply a select all.
query = f'SELECT * FROM "{table_name}"'

SELECT * is not enough, we don't know what is behind the * aat all, a create table with some data will help us and you

I don't think it is possible to read in values over 9999 for the year, as it is an overflow. However, you can replace them with another date to filter them out later, using something like this:
df = pd.read_sql(
    query, 
    oracle_conn,
)
df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], errors='coerce')
df['date_column'].fillna(pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01'), inplace=True)

